# Why does synchronous use of a Promise return asynchronous results?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

**The code**

I actually thought that the new Ecmascript 6 Promise implementation was synchronous in its inner workings (with good use for simplifying asynchronous operations). I then made this example, which I perceive as synchronous code:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {

    foo = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {

        console.log(i);
        resolve(i);
    });

    foo.then (function(i) {

        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

and to my surprise it returns:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

I would have expected synchronous code to return:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

**Question**

What is the explanation for the result returned by the above code?

Comment: onFulfilled/onRejected in a Promise .then are basically asynchronous - see [specs](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34)

Comment: Ok. But should that not result in more "random" results. The order of the result is exactly the same each time I run the code: it first creates the `Promise`'s and then it calls the `.then` one by one in exactly the order the `Promise`'s was created .... ?

Comment: resolve(i) is called in order, 0 to 9, so, would be added onto the execution stack in that order, not some random order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `Promise` constructor, it will synchronously invoke the function you gave to it, which may or may not include a synchronous call to its `resolve` or `reject`.  Regardless of whether it has been resolved/rejected, the returned `Promise` has a [`then` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype.then) which you pass another function to, and again the code within `then` (note, not your callback) is executed synchronously, where we arrive at step 7:

> Return PerformPromiseThen(promise, onFulfilled, onRejected, resultCapability).

[`PerformPromiseThen`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) has a number of steps, but both step 8b and 9b result in a call to [`EnqueueJob`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enqueuejob) depending on whether it was resolved/rejected, where this says:

> Add pending at the back of the Job Queue named by queueName.

(queueName in this instance being "PromiseJobs")

We can then follow the spec further to see how the jobs on the PromiseJobs queue are invoked, but ultimately they are not dequeued and executed while any other code is running - ie the `for` loop will run to completion before any `then` callbacks are invoked.

Comment: Thank you! Is this information part of the Ecma 6 Language Specification?

Comment: @rabbitco Yes - all the links in my answer go to the relevant parts of the spec